# Unable to mount nexus 4

Tags: 13.04, mount, android

I have installed 13.04 & I can't mount my nexus 4. 
Here's the error.

**Unable to open MTP device'[usb:002,007]'**

Any ideas??

Comment: Do you got `gvfs-mtp` package ?

Comment: The android lockscreen denies access to the phones data when the device is in standby/locked. Unlock and try again. If it still does not work, replug it once.

Answer (score 2):

It's really weird, but I solved the issue by closing Banshee Media Player that ran in the background. Turning it back on has resumed the problem.

Comment: Somehow it works on Linux Mint too.

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Thanks, +1.

Comment: This is really not a generally useful answer. For example, it is only interesting to people who have heard of and are running the Banshee Media Player.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following link out. It worked for me.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2004182

Comment: That solution still uses mtpfs. Let's rather go with the `gvfs-mtp` solution and forget about the other stuff entirely. The udev rules are just for configuring developer access (namely adb and fastboot). http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

Comment: It worked nicely :) Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and LiveWireBT [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307252/unable-to-mount-nexus-4#comment388561_307252) helped me:

> The android lockscreen denies access to the phones data when the
>   device is in standby/locked. Unlock and try again. If it still does
>   not work, replug it once. – LiveWireBT Jun 14 at 21:18

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.. did everything none worked except this.. I have Htc one 4.2.2 & ubuntu 13.04..
Go to Synaptic package manager, search for "mtpfs".. install go-mtpsfs-unity..
use mount android appilcation via unity launcher.. right click android icon.. choose mount option.. & there u r.. works perfectly.. though i would like this feature to be default & included in further Ubuntu update.
Hope this helps :D

Comment: there's no go-mtpsfs-unity  :( I only found mtpfs and mtpfs-simple. But both don't get me to mount my Nexus 4. #12.04

Answer (score 0):

What I've usually done, is to set my Android device in PTP mode instead of MTP. I haven't had any problems with that. It's in the USB connection settings on the Android device.